# 98 jeep cherokee wont start. get one click then everything shuts down no more dash lights or nothing

Tags: electrical, starting, jeep

replaced the starter a month or so ago and has started fine, until today.... i turn the key and all power is lost. i tried jumping it, charging the battery, hot wired the starter and still nothing.... turn the key off and try back a few mins later and have all the power back until i turn it into the on position, then ill either get one click then power is gone or no click no power... please help!

Answer (score 3):

There is a connection problem at your battery or in the cables. This usually happens at the battery post, whether a top or side post model. The cable is getting enough of a connection to run the lights and such, which is relatively low load. As soon as you touch the starter, which is a high load, you lose the connection and everything goes black. Please remove both sides of the battery connection, clean the posts really well, then re-tighten  everything up, ensuring you have a good connection.